# "The given key 'utf8mb4' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

i have a problem with sql in C#.

I try to use ExecuteReader(), i get an error in this line:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = readcmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
```

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131577
  Nachricht = The given key 'utf8mb4' was not present in the dictionary.
  Quelle = System.Private.CoreLib
  Stapelüberwachung:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException[T](T key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.set_CharacterSetIndex(Int32 value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetTypeAndFlags(MySqlDbType type, ColumnFlags flags)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at decustomer___LAP_Projekt.MainWindow.MySQLConnector()
```

I thought it was a problem with Visual Studio or XAMPP.

I tried
- add CHARSET=utf8 to the connection string
- changing the "utf8mb4" to "utf8_german2_ci" in database
- Execute SET NAMES 'utf8'
- Updating MySQL
- Tried on other client
- Set up a new mysql server with MySQL Installer 8.0.20 (before: xampp)

The code snippets:

```
string connStr = CreateConnStr("localhost", "xxx", "root", "");
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
connection.Open();


public static string CreateConnStr(string server, string databaseName, string user, string pass)
        {

string connStr = "server=" + server + ";database=" + databaseName + ";uid=" +
user + ";password=" + pass + ";CHARSET=utf8;pooling=false;Allow User Variables=True";
return connStr;
        }
...
string readcmdQuery = "SELECT id, vorname, nachname FROM berater;CharSet=utf8;";
sqlcmd.CommandText = readcmdQuery;
MySqlDataReader reader = readcmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
consList.Items.Clear();
while(reader.Read())
...
```

Please help me. I don't found other solutions in the internet.

Comment: You shouldn't be attaching stuff like `CharSet=utf8;` on the end of your queries. That's a connection string (DSN) thing.

Comment: The information you provided about what you have TRIED already, please add some more clarity to it.

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET` `utf8mb4` is needed for Emoji and Chinese.  `CHARACTER SET utf8` is adequate for German (and the rest of Europe).  The first part of a collation must match the character set name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be using a *very* old version of MySql.Data; the problem you're reporting sounds like [bug 58244](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58244), which was fixed a long time ago.

Or perhaps you've found a slightly different variant of that bug that manifests under slightly different conditions. If so, you could report it at https://bugs.mysql.com/ and wait for a fixed version.

However, I would recommend uninstalling MySql.Data and installing [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead. It's supported `utf8mb4` from the beginning, adds async support, and [fixes many other bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).